# Merging same title data in React Native SectionList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In React Native SectionList's you have data like this for a heading and data (modified for my example):

`const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Main dishes',
    data: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Drinks',
    data: ['Water', 'Coke', 'Beer'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: ['Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream'],
  },
];`

As you can see there are 2 `Sides` titles. Is there an easy way to merge the 2 arrays of `data` so it looks like this:

`data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps', 'Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream']`

As my data comes in randomly it is possible to have data entered this way. Here is my code....

`    fbDb.ref('job')
        .orderByChild('driver_key')
        .equalTo(global.session.user.key)
        .once('value', snapshot => {

```
        const result = [];
        let dayData = { title: "", data: [] };
        let data = snapshot.val();

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
            const timestamp = data[key].status_rfc; //Get timestamp of completed time
            const date = moment(timestamp).format("YYYY MM"); //Change to 2020 02 for date sorting
            if (dayData.title === date) { //If date exists add it to that section header
                dayData.data.push(data[key]);
            } else { //Otherwise add as new entry
                dayData = { title: date, data: [data[key]] };
                result.push(dayData);
            }
        }    

        this._isMounted && this.setState({
            myData: result,
            loading: false,
        });

  });`
```

As you can see it will only work if the data is already ordered by date. Is there an easy way to just group the common titles?

Thanks

Comment: You should have a look at lodash's groupBy function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are asking for this:

> As you can see there are 2 Sides titles. Is there an easy way to merge
>   the 2 arrays of data so it looks like this:
>
> data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps', 'Cheese Cake',
>   'Ice Cream']

Just apply javascript.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Main dishes',
    data: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Drinks',
    data: ['Water', 'Coke', 'Beer'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: ['Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream'],
  },
];

var filter_data = {};

DATA.forEach(e => {

  if(filter_data[e.title] != undefined){
    filter_data[e.title].data = [...filter_data[e.title].data, ...e.data]
  }else{
    filter_data[e.title] = e;
  }

});

var _data = Object.values(filter_data);
console.log(_data);

output:

[{"title":"Main dishes","data":["Pizza","Burger","Risotto"]},
{"title":"Sides","data":["French Fries","Onion Rings","Fried Shrimps","Cheese 
Cake","Ice Cream"]},{"title":"Drinks","data":["Water","Coke","Beer"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to using lodash, this solution may help you:

```
const groupedByTitle = _.groupBy(DATA, "title");
const groupedData = [];

for (const key of Object.keys(groupedByTitle)) {
    const values = groupedByTitle[key].map(value => value.data).flat();
    const group = { title: key, data: values };
    groupedData.push(group);
}
```

The data you are looking for will be in the groupedData array - this will also support situations where the title could end up occurring more than twice.